# Jquery selector performance & behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange question about jquery selector behavior.

First approach:

```
$('#div').find('#something').html('hahah');
$('#div').find('#something').html('hahah');
$('#div').show();
```

Second approach:

```
var $div = $('#div');
$div.find('#something').html('hahah');
$div.find('#something').html('hahah');
$div.show();
```

I know that it might not have too much difference, but is the second faster than the first?? I've always used the second approach but I'm not sure if there is a difference because I don't know how the jquery selector algorithm works.

Comment: it will be because jQuery will not have to look up the node in dom, as its stored in memory

Comment: essentially second one is faster. There is no need to traverse DOM again as the reference is already present.

Comment: sorry about the possible duplicate, I made a research before I asked the question, but I found nothing

Comment: thank you @Vikash. I have imagined that, but I was not sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second way is faster/better because you have *cached* the selector.

Everytime you call `$('selector')`, the `jQuery` selector engine(*sizzle*) is called to locate your desired elements.

However, when you store them in a variable, you do not need to repeatedly call the selector engine as the results are stored.

Note, in your example above, caching can be further improved by storing the `find()` result as well

```
var $something = $('#div').find('#something');
$something.html('hahah');
$something.html('hahah');
$something.show();
```

Comment: Thank you man! it works as I thought, but I was not sure... PS: make your post as answer is not available.